# Using Bootstrap CDN in my Chrome Extension Popup doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I used the Bootstrap CDN to use it in my Chrome Extension as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="player_name" style="text-align:center"></h1>
    <div class="card">
        <img id="player_img">
        <h1></h1>
        <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
            A simple primary alert—check it out!
        </div>
        <div><span>Age: </span><span id="player_age"></span></div>
        <div><span>Position: </span><span id="player_pos"></span></div>
        <div><span>Nationality: </span><span id="player_nation"></span></div>
        <div><span>Preferred Foot: </span><span id="player_foot"></span></div>
        <button class="pure-button">A Pure Button</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Expecting this part to appear:

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                A simple primary alert—check it out!
            </div>
```

However, it gives me this without ANY error in the console

[image]

The `popup.js` has nothing related to it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Also add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to head, to fix the `—` borking.

Comment: also cards are a v4 feature, your using v3

Comment: Did this helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class as `alert-primary` in bootstrap. You can use one of the below classes or create one of your own:

- alert-success
- alert-info
- alert-warning
- alert-danger